# windows-rs ObjectFromLresult

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, windows-rs

I'm trying to export working code I have in C# to Rust using the official window rust crate [windows-rs](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs) (basically doing the exact same calls just with their Rust alternative).

I'm double checking that the handle points to a ***Internet Explorer_Server*** class handle. I'm getting the following error.

> result = Err(Error { code: HRESULT(0x80070057), message: "The parameter is incorrect." })

I also couldn't find a single example of using ***ObjectFromLresult*** in Rust [GitHub search](https://github.com/search?q=ObjectFromLresult+language%3ARust+&type=code).

[How to reproduce - GitHub repo](https://github.com/ohaddahan/windows-rs-usage/tree/master)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: In the linked code, I'm not sure that the `response` usage is correct. It is a pointer to a temporary, not a `LPARAM`. You can try defining it as a variable and passing `&mut response` where a pointer is needed.

Comment: @rodrigo I'm pretty sure you're correct but it's not 100% clear to me. You're referring to the SendMessageTimeoutW usage? The function signature requires Option<*mut usize>.

Comment: @IInspectable added a repo with the test UI and code used https://github.com/ohaddahan/windows-rs-usage/tree/master .

Comment: More in the `ObjectFromLresult()`, you are passing `LRESULT(response as isize)` as argument, but `response` is a pointer to the value, maybe `LRESULT((*response) as isize)` would work. But where is that pointer pointing to? To a nameless temporary, I guess, but I would prefer that it had a name.

Comment: @rodrigo you're right! Thank you. Please submit as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] **in the question itself**. Offsite resources tend to become inaccessible over time, rendering the question and answer(s) useless.

Comment: @IInspectable the example if far too big to embed it here, unless there is a feature for full repos I'm unaware of.